# Does IDbDependencyResolver only work with parameterless constructors?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, autofac

I've been trying to inject a service into my IDbInterceptor using [this](https://github.com/rowanmiller/Demo-EF6Advanced/blob/master/CompletedSourceCode/AdventureWorks/Global.asax.cs) example. Resolving the interceptor with its dependencies (ITenantContext) works fine as long as I don't register AutofacDbDependencyResolver with DbConfiguration.

However when I do I get the error `An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'DMDbContext'. ---> ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.`. The error does not appear if I change my ITenantContext to use a parameterless constructor but that defeats the whole purpose of DI.

This is my IoC-container:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();  
builder.RegisterType<TenantIdDMDbCommandInterceptor>().As<IDbInterceptor>();
builder.RegisterType<DMDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope(); 

builder.RegisterType<WebJobsTenantContext>().As<ITenantContext().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterInstance(config);

// Need to register webjob class in Autofac as well
builder.RegisterType<Functions>().InstancePerDependency();

var container = builder.Build();

//This line causes the exception
DbConfiguration.Loaded += (s, e) =>
     e.AddDependencyResolver(new AutofacDbDependencyResolver(container), overrideConfigFile: false);
```

And this is my IDbDependency resolver:

```
public class AutofacDbDependencyResolver : IDbDependencyResolver
{
    private ILifetimeScope container;

    public AutofacDbDependencyResolver(ILifetimeScope container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type type, object key)
    {
        if (container.IsRegistered(type))
        {
            return container.Resolve(type); //TODO: Why does this only work with parameterless contructors?
        }

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type type, object key)
    {
        if (container.IsRegistered(type))
        {
            return new object[] { container.Resolve(type) };
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<object>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This errors means that one of your services resolved by a IDbDependencyResolver is dependent on DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

Check the parameter types on the WebJobsTenantContext concrete class.

if the types themselves are registered with the DI engine, only then the chained resolution will happen.

if they are non-DI registered parameter types (primitive types etc.), then you need to let the DI engine know, about its values.

```
builder.RegisterType<WebJobsTenantContext>()
.WithParameter("param1", someValue)
.As<ITenantContext().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```